# How to draw a costom cube in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I just want to draw one cube, such as one building(I got the places on the ground which is consisted of four points),and I also knew the height of the building. So how to draw? Thanks very much.

Comment: check out how "Three.CubeGeometry" is created and get your head around it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward:
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/CubeGeometry

```
var building = new THREE.CubeGeometry(width, height, depth, 1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xFF0000 });

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(building, material);

scene.add(mesh);
```